# JqueryUI autocomplete input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a situation where I need to change the value of an input field when an autocomplete option has been selected from the dropdown. The problem is that the source for the autocomplete widget consists of objects that have an index and a label. The form that will send the data must take the index but display the label.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" name="field" type="text">
```

JS:

```
values = [
  {label: "aaaaaa", id: 1},
  {label: "aaabbb", id: 2},
  {label: "aaaccc", id: 3},
];

$("#input").autocomplete({
  source: values,
  select: function (event, ui){
    // change #input to ui.item.id
  }
});
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uszu4ud/6/))

When submit the form should contain the index not the label in the input field.

My first thought was changing the input element's value in the select event, which worked in HTML but the submit data did not reflect the change, which made me think that the widget is wrapping the input field and storing the data somewhere else. Also, selecting a value from the autocorrect dropdown does not change the input element's value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work when adding `return false` to the select function. Cancels the default, which, as the manual mentions, is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: values,
    select: function (event, ui){
        $("#input").val(ui.item.id);
        return false;
    }
});
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k30yryuf/))

This way you could have a hidden field in the form that sends the id, while still displaying the title (value).

A slightly unusual case of RTFM.

Comment: Adding `return false` to the end is useful if you're using jQuery UI's Autocomplete on the new HTML5 input number type and you just want the ID but still want to keep the text label for the autocomplete.